# Is Ibeacon of ios can connect with android beacon technology and vice versa?

Tags: android, ios, ibeacon, android-ibeacon

We want to create an app for ios that will use ibeacon, and we are not sure if when we also develop our app in android it will be compatible with ios ibeacon? we can connect cross-platform?

Comment: Beacons are just a "specific part"  of Bluetooth Low-Energy. If your device supports BLE (if it have the BLE chip especially), no issue if it's an Android one or a iOS one.

Comment: Android apps can't detect iBeacons in the background. You may want to look at a dual technology beacon that can advertise ibeacon and Eddystone at the same time.

Comment: Yes. An Android app. can periodically scan for and discover iBeacons. Either with an Activity in the foreground or with a Service in the background. No problem and no need for dual technology beacons. [Here's some example code.](https://kittensandcode.blogspot.fi/2014/08/ibeacons-and-android-parsing-uuid-major.html)

Comment: @MarkusKauppinen Yeah thanks for that but how about ios detecting android beacon devices? is this also possible or can we also use android devices as a beacon? sorry for my questions I'm really a newbie in this field.

Comment: I'm not familiar with iOS, but the I've understood that iOS has better support for Apple's own iBeacons (with `Core Location`), but it's possible to detect other beacons as well (with `Core Bluetooth`). See for example [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34240751/eddystone-beacon-detecting-issue#answer-34268599). An Android device (some specific Android devices only) can act as a beacon (even as iBeacon) if that's what you really want.